# Domain model that needs to store another domain model

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Suppose I have the following simple Domain Model setup:

```
class Event { ... }

class PlannedEvent { Event event; DateTime date; .. }
```

And I would like to plan events as descriptive as possible I would write it as

```
class Event {   

    public void plan(DateTime date) {
        // Can I create and Store a PlannedEvent here ?
        // in other words access a Repository
    }
```

I add the plan method because from within the Ubiquitous language you Plan an Event which results in a Planned Event somewhere in the Future. So it feels natural to put the plan method in the Event class.

I've always read that you must not use repostories in domain objects I can understand why , but how would I solve the above then ?

Is this where Domain Events come into play ?

```
class Event {   

    public void plan(DateTime date) {
        DomainEventPublisher
            .instance()
            .publish(new PlannedEventCreated(this, date)));
    }
```

Where the Domain Event will make sure a PlannedEvent will be created and stored (by a repository) ?

Comment: From what I can see, Event is an aggregate root while PlannedEvent - an entity within it. Repository should persist the whole aggregate. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I don't see a PlannedEvent as an Entity within Event. An Event must be seen as a type of Event like cleaning for example. It's rather the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Is it conceivable that both Event and PlannedEvent are aggregate roots? I doubt that Event should know anything about PlannedEvent, certainly not how to construct one ­-- this is out of it's scope. Evans states about factories:

> When creation of an object, or an entire AGGREGATE becomes complicated or reveals too much of the internal structure, FACTORIES provide encapsulation.

Maybe you use an aggregate factory to build a PlannedEvent for an Event. In order to decouple the two, I would prefer to reference the Event by some unique Event-ID from within the PlannedEvent instead of a direct object reference. You can use this ID to lookup an Event via its repository.

Comment: Yes from where I stand they are both aggregate roots. I can follow you when you say an Event should know nothing about a PlannedEvent. 
But in my Ubiquitous language you plan an Event. So that's how Event.plan method araised. But it feels to me that a factory would be a total overkill.

Comment: What's about a static factory method in the PlannedEvent class that takes an Event and Date as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You may use Event as PlannedEvent's factory:

```
class Event {   

    public PlannedEvent plan(DateTime date) {
        return new PlannedEvent(getId(), date,...);
    }
}  


class PlanningService {//This is an application service
    public void plan(String eventId) {
        Event event = eventRepository.findBy(eventId);
        PlannedEvent pe = event.plan(clock.now());
        plannedEventRepository.store(pe);
    }

}
```

And of course, it is better to have a PlannedEventFactory if things get complex.

You don't store PlannedEvent inside Event. Let the domain model(or an extra factory) provide some kind of factory method to create PlannedEvent and let the repository do the job.

Comment: To me this smells a bit like inappropriate intimacy (http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/inappropriate-intimacy) because a PlannedEvent must of course be aware of the Event concept while the Event does not necessarily have to know about PlannedEvents. In my opinion it was more straightforward with an unidirectional association.

Comment: @mdo Maybe you're right. but from "I've always read that you must not use repostories in domain objects", I infer that the question focuses on how to store the aggregate root created rather than how to create one. I think the key is to use some kind of factory pattern and let the repository do the job. Answer updated, thanks.